# Thread-safe queue with tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, task

I have some kind of work manager in c# which will receive tasks to do and it will execute them. Task will be arriving from different threads, but they must be executed only one at the same time in the order they were received.
I don't want a while loop, which will be running all the time, checking if they are new tasks in the queue. Is there a built-in queue or an easy way to implement a queue which will wait for tasks and execute them synchronously without busy-waiting?

Comment: I don't think there is build functionality for this pattern but you can build one  without while loop through **SemaphoreSlim**

Comment: Did you check [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [Queue.Synchronized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: TPL Dataflow is one way to go, considering your requirement that it isn't running all of the time. You can control how it's executed (in terms of threads, etc.) so I think you should be able to ensure that only one runs at a time. Be careful you don't create a backlog though.

Comment: _"I don't want a while loop"_ do you want to run them on the threadpool? I've made a WorkerThread which is waiting for items to be executed. (it will be signalled to start. It also support batches. But it spawns a thread with a while loop)

Comment: BlockingCollection (which is a base element of TPL DataFlow) is what you are looking for. And there is no busy-waiting although it might look like. The waiting is done by an event and there is no cost of cpu time => not busy but waiting

Comment: For future reference, what you're looking for is called a [producer/consumer queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). If your producer and consumer are both synchronous, `BlockingCollection<T>` is a great solution. If either is asynchronous, then `BufferBlock<T>` from TPL Dataflow is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments you should look into [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) but also [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) and use GetConsumingEnumerable() instead of your unwanted WHILE loop

```
BlockingCollection<YourClass> _collection =
            new BlockingCollection<YourClass>(new ConcurrentQueue<YourClass>());

_collection.Add() can be called from multiple threads
```

On a separate thread you can use

```
foreach (var message in _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{}
```

Comment: The request is to do it one at the same time

Comment: His sentence is unclear "but they must be executed only one at the same time". I'm assuming he wants them to be executed ONE at a time in a sequential manner

Comment: "but they must be executed **only one** at the same time"

Comment: @DanielTshuva I think we're saying the same thing here. Messages will be processed one at a time in the order that they were received.

Comment: Looking into the docs, you don't need to specify ConcurrentQueue<T> because that is the default.  But you could specify other collections like ConcurrentStack<T> for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SemaphoreSlim (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) and a ConcurrentQueue

Example:

```
    private delegate void TaskBody();

    private class TaskManager
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<TaskBody>
            TaskBodyQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskBody>();

        private readonly SemaphoreSlim 
            TaskBodySemaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

        public async void Enqueue(TaskBody body)
        {
            TaskBodyQueue.Enqueue(body);

            await TaskBodySemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"Cycle ...");

            if (TaskBodyQueue.TryDequeue(out body) == false) {
                throw new InvalidProgramException($"TaskBodyQueue is empty!");
            }

            body();

            Console.WriteLine($"Cycle ... done ({TaskBodyQueue.Count} left)");

            TaskBodySemaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var tm = new TaskManager();

        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 30), async number => {
            await Task.Delay(100 * number);

            tm.Enqueue(delegate {
                Console.WriteLine($"Print {number}");
            });
        });

        Task
            .Delay(4000)
            .Wait();

        WaitFor(action: "exit");
    }

    public static void WaitFor(ConsoleKey consoleKey = ConsoleKey.Escape, string action = "continue")
    {
        Console.Write($"Press {consoleKey} to {action} ...");

        var consoleKeyInfo = default(ConsoleKeyInfo);

        do {
            consoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        while (Equals(consoleKeyInfo.Key, consoleKey) == false);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a good solution, but BlockingCollection seems to be easier and simplier for this problem.